# Karate - Setting global request headers

Tags: karate

So I've managed to write a bunch of tests and in every feature file I set the same request headers.

For example:

```
Given url appUrl
And path '/path'
* header Accept = 'application/json'
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to set a header once so that it is set before each scenario is run. I've read the documentation and tried the callSingle method as follows in karate-config.js:

```
karate.callSingle('classpath:api/Utilities/Feature/header.feature');
```

header.feature looks like:

```
Feature: common routing that sets the headers for all features

  Background:
    * configure headers = { Accept : 'application/json' }
```

And example feature where I expect the headers to be preset:

```
 Feature: Header Preset

      Scenario: I expect the header to be set
        Given url appUrl
        And path '/path'
        When method get
        Then status 200
        * print response
       #I expect the response to be returned in JSON format
```

However I'm unable to get this working. I don't think I've understood how the callSingle method works. Some pointers would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignore `callSingle` for now and focus on [`configure headers`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#http-header-manipulation).

I think you are missing one step - which is to ensure that `configure headers` has been "applied" before each `Scenario`. If you are 100% sure that this applies "globally", just do this in `karate-config.js`:

```
karate.configure('headers', { Accept: 'application/json' });
```

Else you use the `Background` (in each feature):

```
* configure headers = { Accept: 'application/json' }
```

Typically you have more steps that are common, so you have them in a "common" feature file and `call` that for every test. Refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#shared-scope

Comment: Just what the doctor ordered. I'll be using the callSingle method to set Basic auth headers so it wasn't a complete waste of time pursuing that route after all.
Thanks Peter.

Comment: Can we pass variable reference in configure headers?

Comment: I am using karate 1.4.0. It looks like karate.configure('headers'....) does not set the headers. I have to do explicitly with * configure headers. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

For custom headers - in each feature file

```
  * configure headers = read('file:src/test/java/common/set-headers.js')
```

set-headers.js -

```
function fn() {
  return {
    "header1": header1_value,
    "header2": header2_value
  };
}
```